# How to implement the priority of expressions Bakus-Naur Form

Tags: bnf, ebnf, grako, tatsu

There is a grammar of this kind described in the documentation:

```
grammar
    =
    | ['()'] ['$'] {'#' &'#'} '#'
    | ['()'] {'#' &'#'} '#%'
    | ['()'] ['$'] {'0' &'0'} '0'
    | ['()'] {'0' &'0%'} '0%'
    | ['()'] ['$'] {'#' &'0'} {'0' &'0'} '0'
    ;
```

How to correctly describe the grammar so that when you try to parse a string, you get the following result:

For string `'######'` we get the result `(['#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], '#')` it's True (worked first rule)

For string `'#####%'` we get the result `(['#', '#', '#', '#'], '#')` it's False it should be `(['#', '#', '#', '#'], '#%')` (worked first but should have been second rule)

For string `'000000'` we get the result `(['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], '0')` it's True (worked third rule)

For string `'###000'` we get the result `(['#', '#'], '#')` it's False (worked first but should have been fifth rule)

Are the rules given in the documentation absurd or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Tatsu try rules in the order they are declared.

So in your example:

```
| ['()'] ['$'] {'#' &'#'} '#'
| ['()'] {'#' &'#'} '#%'
```

The first rule will successfully match `#####` before even reading the `%`

Reversing the two options will make Tatsu try to parse `#%` first, and only try `#` if it fails.

**NB:** the `~` symbol can also be used to avoid trying other options for a rule once a pattern has been successfully parsed.